# WebSocket error occurred: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I try to create connection to cable server and subscribe on channel, but  I get error with log:

```
Started GET "/cable" for 172.20.0.1 at 2017-05-27 08:29:39 +0000
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 172.20.0.1 at 2017-05-27 08:29:39 +0000
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
WebSocket error occurred: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

My code:

```
// order_slots.coffee
jQuery(document).ready ->
  //some jquery code that call create_channel function

create_channel = (order_id) ->
  App.cable.subscriptions.create {
    channel: "OrderSlotsChannel",
    order_id: order_id
  },
    connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

    disconnected: ->
      # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

    received: (data) ->
      # Data received
```

Specific channel:

```
//order_slots_channel
class OrderSlotsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "order_slots_#{params[:order_id]}_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed; end
end
```

And ActionCable connection:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file. Action Cable runs in a loop that does not support auto reloading.
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user
      verified_user = env['warden'].user
      verified_user || reject_unauthorized_connection
    end
  end
end
```

ActionCable::Channel::Base - is just empty. I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you checked your this code: `create_channel = (order_id) ->
  App.cable.subscriptions.create {
    channel: "OrderSlotsChannel",
    order_id: order_id
  }`

I think it should have only one parameter i.e channel name i.e "order_slots_#{order_id}_channel"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem. The project used Passenger Phusion as application server and 5.0.x version badly combine with rails 5.1 and action cable. You should update passenger up to 5.1.x

Answer (score 1):

Posting this here because I found it difficult to find much info on this error. I had this same issue with ruby 3, rails 7, and passenger 6.0.1. upgrading to 6.0.17 fixed the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).